# Why in web os simulator no preview after compile the code in web os ide?

Tags: webos, lg

[image]- I'm getting an error as below and no preview in LGTV simulator update as code compile. According to screenshot the program was install but no preview in simulator.

- "[Launch] User request is not completed because of a internal timeout"
- I have tried uninstall whole program and reinstall but result was same.
- Have tried windows firewall disable but result was same.
- Have tried downgrade version on simulator but result was same.